# How to send a netbios broadcast

Tags: netbios, broadcast

I am testing some feature of a firewall and I want to send a netbios broadcast packet out. How do I this?

I tried nbtstat -A "ip-addr" but this sends a unicast message not a broadcast.

Comment: Broadcast per what protocol? EthernetII, IP, NetBEUI ?

Comment: Ethernet layer II or IP.